# Rails environment variables with Rack-Mini-Profiler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I'm trying to understand how the Rails 'rack-mini-profiler' actually dumps out environment variables when you append the `?pp=env` on the base URL of a request.  Right now my Gemfile has the `gem 'dotenv-rails` configured and I'm using .env.local to populate some test variables.  My question is, where is the rack-mini-profiler getting the environment variables from?  There are many different ways to populate env variables within a rails app, dotenv being one of them.  I've been perusing the source code of rack-mini-profiler and can't seem to find it.  I see the `dump_env` function in 'profiler.rb' but I can't see where or how these environment variables are getting pulled from within the code.  It is only showing the printing of them by using a do loop of key/value pairs.  Here is the example application I'm playing with and you can see the environment variables at this URL:  https://preprod.rtcfingroup.com/?pp=env
Appreciate any insight.  Really trying to understand this at a low level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miniprofiler does not actually have do anything since Ruby exposes the environmental variables through [the `ENV` constant](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/ENV.html) which is a hash like class.

[`dump_env` just iterates over them](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/3cb877bad44f50530dcb94bed349004636169b4c/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb#L480):

```
body << "\n\nEnvironment\n---------------\n"
ENV.each do |k, v|
  body << "#{k}: #{v}\n"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  So to really understand the ENV constant more, you would just to have to understand all of the different methods that a ruby application uses to populate ENV constant.  One example being the dotenv-rails gem.

Comment: In looking at the code further, there is a section that prints "Rack Environment" and loops through "env.each".  Then there is a section that prints "Environment" and loops through "ENV.each".  Could you clarify the difference on what is exposed in that class with ENV versus env?

Comment: `ENV` is a set of accessors that get the environmental variables of the system itself, so its really like a wrapper around c functions like getenv.

Comment: Every Rack application such as Sinatra and Rails take a single argument which is a hash thats called `env`. It contains information about the request like parameters, headers and server configuration. Every piece of middleware like Rack-Mini-Profiler takes the env hash as input and then passes it along in the chain so it can also be used to pass information along. Some middleware like Warden injects itself into env.

Comment: Thank you.  This is helpful in explaining this.  Desire to understand this inside and out.  When I type ENV at a shell, or when i type ENV from within 'irb', I don't see those simulated sensitive API key env variables that are showing in the '?pp=env' at the end (sample URL above), or in the .env.local within rails app home dir.  Is that because they are not instantiating the same env variables as the rails app is using?  Is there a way to mimic that within a shell to compare?

Comment: If you add `export` in front of the you declarations in the .env file you can source the file with `source .env.local` in bash. You can list the env vars on linux and os-x with `env | less` or `printenv | less`.

Comment: In a plain `irb` terminal you need to run `require 'dotenv'; Dotenv.load` for dotenv to actually load any env vars from your files. I stopped using dotenv in favor of direnv years ago though which is language agnostic and hooks into the shell itself.

Comment: Thanks.  That works and I can see what 'rack' sees with both a shell / export method as well as irb with commands above.  This explains why regular shell can't see the same env variables that rack and middleware can see.  They aren't receiving that ENV hash.  Are there commands with shell or irb that can distinguish between ENV and env with how rack-mini-profiler "env_dump" function loops between them separately?  Still not understanding how to delineate them separately outside of rack-mini-profiler.

Comment: There is no ambiguity. `ENV` is a constant and `env` is local variable (well an argument really).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.